# Does anyone remember a short story about little gnat-like aliens who are trying to show a human how plastic can be turned into gold?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, short-stories

I think it was in a sci fi anthology about 25 years ago. The human in the story is aware of them as little bugs which won't leave him alone. They are trying to pay him back for help he gave them unknowingly with their research. (I think.)

He is under a lot of pressure at work because he needs to find a way to recycle plastic or something. The aliens keep trying to help him and he keeps throwing their work away, unaware of what they are doing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds like ["The Gift of Garigolli"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51742) by Frederik Pohl and C. M. Kornbluth. I read it in an anthology (*Galaxy, Volume 2*). According to the table of contents it appeared in the August 1974 edition of *Galaxy*.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm pretty sure that this is it. I have my librarian friend trying to track it down and I've also ordered a copy of one of the anthologies listed in the above mentioned link. Between the two, I will find it and let you know if that's it for sure.  I'm thinking I should wait until then to accept an answer.  If I'm wrong on that, feel free to let me know!

Comment: I'm confirming that, yes, it is The Gift of Garigolli as referenced above. Thank you for helping me find it!

Comment: knowing nothing about the story but what the OP described I would have guessed the author as either Pohl or Kornbluth ...